# How to recreate this table effect

Tags: php, html, css

I was wondering how I could recreate this table from this image. For my class project we are supposed to redesign this page, however I have no idea how to implement anything like that. It seems almost as if someone embedded an excel spreadsheet in the page.

[image: Here is the picture of the Table.]

Comment: You could do it with CSS, but this screenshot doesnt look like it was taken of a web page... it might have been, but it looks more like some VB application someone has made

Comment: Well that explains a lot. And also why the company the college is outsourcing us to has such strange expectations. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a table header to add the blue background to the top row with CSS.

```
th { background: some blue-ish color}
```

Add a fixed width div (the table should be inside this div) and use overflow: scroll; for the scrollbar effect.

Rowspan for the first column.

Pretty basic CSS stuff, do you need to add functionality too or just the CSS?

Comment: Thanks. It has full excel functionality which is what I was trying to figure out if I could recreate.

Comment: You're welcome. Ah i see, then you would have to use jQuery or php (saw that the question was tagged with "php") if you're allowed to use plugins, maybe you could use something like this: http://handsontable.com/